# Centered textview does not appear in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a TextView, which I need to be centered horizontally and vertically inside a square. To do this, I have put it inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centered_text_view_text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="test"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I instantiate the RelativeLayout with a LayoutInflater and then call the layout method on the RelativeLayout to position it where I need it.

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = Helpers.getInflater();
        containerLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.centered_text_view, null);
        textView = (TextView) containerLayout.findViewById(R.id.centered_text_view_text);
        ... (later in the code)
        containerLayout.layout(dayLeft, weekTop, dayRight, weekBottom);
```

My problem is that the TextView is not visible. I can see the white background for the RelativeLayout, but neither the text nor the background for the TextView.

I have also tried getting rid of the RelativeLayout and calling the layout method on the TextView. I haven't been able to get this to work, however, because the text is only horizontally, and not vertically, aligned after I set the gravity on the TextView.

Comment: In what context are you doing this? Is this a view, activity, fragment or something else?

Comment: This is in a custom view. I'm calling 'layout' in onLayout.

Answer (score 0):

**First** - Custom views should extend some sort of `View.class`. The class to extend should be whatever your root view is in your `xml`.

---

**Second** - You are keeping a reference to `containerLayout` (root view) which is redundant. This class *is* the root view.

Replace `containerLayout` with `this` or just removing entirely:

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.centered_text_view_text);
```

---

**Third** - I can't say how you are inflating is wrong, but I have never done it like that.

Instead of calling `layout` on a `containerLayout`, try inflating with the `inflate()` method. *(You get access to this when extending a sub class of `View`)*

```
inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_user_tag, this);
```

Notice how I am setting `this` as the root, and using the inflater from the view class.

---

**Your class may look like something like this:**

```
public static class TextInLinear extends RelativeLayout { 

     public TextView textView; 

     //region default constructers 

     public void TextInLinear(Context context){
        this(context, null);
     }

     public void TextInLinear(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        this(context, attrs, 0);
     }

     public void TextInLinear(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
         if(!isInEditMode()) init();
     }

     //endregion

     private void init(){
         inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_user_tag, this);
         textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.centered_text_view_text);
     }


     /* more methods. i.e. setText(), getText() or whatever */
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm trying your code, but the program crashes on the line where I inflate:      `public static class TextInLinear {
        public RelativeLayout containerLayout;
        public TextView textView;

        public TextInLinear(Context context, Calendar2 root) {
            containerLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(context, R.layout.centered_text_view, root);
            textView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.centered_text_view_text);
        }
    }`

Comment: @DasunCathir - No. You are still not using the view like you should. If you are creating a custom view the class should extend the root view. See my update. Notice that it is extending `RelativeLayout` and I removed your root view.